# What is the chronological order of the Sono Hanabira games?

Tags: sono-hanabira

I'm curious as to what is the chronological order of the [*Sono Hanabira*](https://vndb.org/v917) series, including the placement of [*Hanahira*](https://vndb.org/v5244) and the [*Sono Hanabira - Tenshi*](https://vndb.org/v12293) games (the latter in relation to *Sono Hanabira*).

I know that some games like Sono Hanabira 4 and 6 are sequels to Sono Hanabira 2 and 1 because their starring couples are already in relationships by this time. I also know that in the second game, Yuuna appears and tries to convince Sara to call Kaede "Onee-sama", and in the third game she encouraged Mai to be honest with her feelings, saying that it feels good to be in love. But in neither of these does Yuuna hint that she's already in a relationship with Nanami, as in the first game Yuuna admits she fell in love with Nanami when they first met when Nanami was lost and was trying to get to the opening ceremony and that she has always wanted to be called Onee-sama.

I also remember in one of the games, some of the characters mentioning the new student which I think is referencing Sara (though I can't remember which games).